# Determining a Winner in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python

I'm looking to write a procedure in python for a 3x3 tic-tac-toe board called `winner(board)` that takes a 2-dimensional list representing a Tic-Tac-Toe board and determines if there is a winner (and if there is a winner, who it is) or if the game ends on a draw. The board uses `'-'` to represent an open position, `'x'` for player 1 and `'o'` for player 2.

I also wish to use the procedures `select_row(array, i)` and `select_col(array,i)`  which accept a 2-dimensional array (represented as a nested list) and an index of a row or column, and returns a list that represents the row or column associated with that index, as well as the procedures `select_main_diag(array)` and `select_counter_diag(array)` that accept a square 2-dimensional array and return a list with the elements of either the main diagonal or counterdiagonal (respectively).

Returns would be as follows:

```
winner([['-','-','-'], ['-','-','-'], ['-','-','-']])
False

winner([['x','x','x'], ['-','-','-'], ['-','-','-']])
'x'

winner([['o', '-','-'], ['-', 'o','-'], ['-','-','o']])
'o'

winner([['-','-','x'], ['-','-','x'], ['-','-', 'x']])
'x'

winner([['x','o','x'], ['x','o','o'], ['o','x','x']])
"Draw"

winner([['x','o','x'], ['x','o','o'], ['o','-','x']])
False
```

And the procedures that I wish to include and use in the code are as follows:

```
def select_row(lst, i):
 return lst[i]

def select_col(lst, i):
   return [lst[idx][i] for idx in range(len(lst))]

def select_main_diag(array):
  return [array[i][i] for i in range(len(array))]

def select_counter_diag(array): 
  return [array[len(array)-i-1][i] for i in range(len(array))]
```

I am completely new to using python and am quite unfamiliar with it, so any advice on this problem -- both how to go about it and how to put it into code -- would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Nate is there any possible scenario where this is not homework?

Comment: It is for a lab in my computer science class. Hence the very specific constraints I must work with.

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker - not likely, but I was simply being polite.

Comment: While they are pretty hard to read you'll find many solutions in [Code Golf: Tic Tac Toe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2245801/2509). As usual, don't take [tag:code-golf] to be indicative of good programming style, and recall that new golf questions (and other objective programming puzzles) should go to [CodeGolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about winner determination:

1. For each row, column, and diagonal: are the three spaces all the same? If so, and they're not empty, then that's the winner.
2. Otherwise, is the board full (i.e. has no empty spaces)? If so it's a draw.
3. Otherwise, there is no winner and the game continues.

Answer (score 0):

In the following implementation, the program tries to maximize the chance for victory. A stronger version would try to minimize the chance for defeat. An alternative strategy would be to learn what moves lead to victory and what moves lead to defeat. As for the winner, `grade_grid(state.grid)` gives an answer.

```
import tkinter
from itertools import product
from math import trunc
from functools import lru_cache, wraps
from random import choice
from sys import modules

################################################################################

class Cross(tkinter.Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title('Demo')
        root.resizable(False, False)
        widget = cls(root)
        widget.grid()
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.__ai = CrossAI()
        space = ' ' * 11
        self.__buttons = {}
        for r, c in product(range(3), range(3)):
            b = tkinter.Button(self, text=space, command=self.__bind(r, c))
            b.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=10, pady=10)
            self.__buttons.setdefault(r, {})[c] = b

    def __bind(self, row, column):
        return lambda: self.click(row, column)

    def click(self, row, column):
        r, c = self.__ai.move(row, column)
        if r != -1 != c:
            self.__buttons[row][column]['text'] = '    X    '
            if r != -2 != c:
                self.__buttons[r][c]['text'] = '    O    '

################################################################################

def enum(names):
    "Create a simple enumeration having similarities to C."
    return type('enum', (), dict(map(reversed, enumerate(
        names.replace(',', ' ').split())), __slots__=()))()

################################################################################

class Static(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, members):
        for name, member in members.items():
            if callable(member):
                members[name] = cls.__wrap(member)
            elif isinstance(member, property):
                members[name] = property(cls.__wrap(member.fget),
                                         cls.__wrap(member.fset),
                                         cls.__wrap(member.fdel),
                                         member.__doc__)
            elif isinstance(member, (classmethod, staticmethod)):
                members[name] = type(member)(cls.__wrap(member.__func__))
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, members)

    @classmethod
    def __wrap(cls, function):
        if function:
            annotations = function.__annotations__
            co_varnames = function.__code__.co_varnames
            if not annotations:
                return function
            @wraps(function)
            def wrapper(*args):
                for arg, name in zip(args, co_varnames):
                    cls.__raise(arg, annotations[name])
                value = function(*args)
                cls.__raise(value, annotations['return'])
                return value
            return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    def __raise(item, klass):
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(None)
        elif isinstance(klass, str):
            klass = vars(modules[item.__module__])[klass]
        if not isinstance(item, klass):
            raise TypeError('{} must be of type {}'.format(item, klass))

################################################################################

class CrossAI(metaclass=Static):

    STATE = enum('changing, victory, defeat, error, draw')

    def __init__(self: 'CrossAI') -> None:
        self.__db = State(((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), 1)

    def move(self: 'CrossAI', row: int, column: int) -> tuple:
        if not self.__db.moves:
            return -1, -1
        self.__make_move(row, column)
        return self.__best_move()

    def __make_move(self: 'CrossAI', row: int, column: int) -> None:
        copy = tuple(map(list, self.__db.grid))
        copy[row][column] = 1
        self.__db = State(tuple(map(tuple, copy)), -1)

    def __best_move(self: 'CrossAI') -> tuple:
        if not self.__db.moves:
            return -2, -2
        score = min(move.grade for move in self.__db.moves)
        moves = tuple(move for move in self.__db.moves if move.grade == score)
        final = choice(moves)
        for r, c in product(range(3), range(3)):
            if self.__db.grid[r][c] != final.grid[r][c]:
                self.__db = State(final.grid, 1)
                return r, c

################################################################################

class State(tuple):

    @lru_cache(None)
    def __new__(cls, grid, next_move):
        return super().__new__(cls, (grid, make_moves(grid, next_move)))

    @property
    def grid(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def moves(self):
        return self[1]

    @property
    def grade(self):
        return grade(*self)

################################################################################

@lru_cache(None)
def make_moves(grid, next_move):
    moves = []
    for r, c in available_moves(grid):
        copy = tuple(map(list, grid))
        copy[r][c] = next_move
        moves.append(State(tuple(map(tuple, copy)), -next_move))
    return frozenset(moves)

@lru_cache(None)
def available_moves(grid):
    return () if grade_grid(grid) else \
        tuple((r, c) for r, c in product(range(3), range(3)) if not grid[r][c])

@lru_cache(None)
def grade(grid, moves):
    return grade_grid(grid) + grade_moves(moves)

@lru_cache(None)
def grade_grid(grid):
    for triplet in combinations(grid):
        grade = trunc(sum(triplet) / 3)
        if grade:
            return grade
    return 0

@lru_cache(None)
def combinations(grid):
    combos = list(grid)
    for c in range(3):
        combos.append(tuple(grid[r][c] for r in range(3)))
    combos.append(tuple(grid[i][i] for i in range(3)))
    combos.append(tuple(grid[i][2 - i] for i in range(3)))
    return combos

@lru_cache(None)
def grade_moves(moves):
    return sum(grade(*move) for move in moves)

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Cross.main()
```